# How to set divs and ids through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to set divs through a loop and set ids as well. Something like the following code. Any help would be really appreciated, Thanks in advance. :)

```
 <body>
 <div class="container"> 
     <div class="left">
         <div class="content">
             <script>
                 for(int i=1; i<=16; i++) {
             </script>
             <div class="card" id=i>       
             </div>
             <script>    
                 }
             </script>

 </body>
```

Comment: there is nothing called as `int` in javascript, do you want to create 16 divs, as a child of `div class="content`.

Comment: You are using client-side JavaScript. It doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, do it like bellow

HTML

```
<div class="conatiner"></div>
<div class="left"></div>

<div class="content"></div>
```

JS

```
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
     var contentDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
      for(var i=1; i<=16; i++){
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.class='card';
        div.id=i;
        contentDiv.appendChild(div);
      }
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple div's as:

```
<script type="text/javscript">
   var contentDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
   for(var i=1; i < 16; i++){
      var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
      newDiv.id = 'card'+i;
      newDiv.className = 'card';
      contentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
   }
</script>
```